# Sort JSON array by date key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, date, sorting

I have a json array and I am trying to **sort it by date** before I append it.

The array looks as such:

```
result = [];
result.push(
  {id: 'ID', result: {url: 'test', date: '15 May 2013, 6:40 pm'}},
  {id: 'ID', result: {url: 'test', date: '20 Dec 2012, 8:00 am'}},
  {id: 'ID', result: {url: 'test', date: '29 Jun 2012, 5:47 pm'}}
);
```

Currently, **I have managed to sort an array** of dates as such:

```
var datearray = [
    '2011-05-26 12:00:00',
    '2016-01-26 12:00:00',
    '2011-01-26 12:00:00',
    '2012-12-08 07:00:00',
    '2011-01-26 12:00:00',
    '1995-01-05 06:00:00'
];

datearray.sort();
```

which gives me:

```
1995-01-05 06:00:00
2011-01-26 12:00:00
2011-01-26 12:00:00
2011-05-26 12:00:00
2012-12-08 07:00:00
2016-01-26 12:00:00
```

but **Im not sure how to do the same for a complex array** which contains more keys than one. I know that *I should firstly format the date to YYYY-MM-DD* but after im kinda messed up.

A good start would be from what I currently came up with found on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ipatok/8/edit

Comment: On second thought the linked duplicate question goes into greater detail (no sense in repeating good information)

Comment: None of these duplicates explain how a complex array is sorted

Comment: @jQuerybeast If by "complex array" you mean an array of dictionaries, that is exactly what the duplicate shows. In your case you would simply parse the strings in `a.result.date` and `b.result.date` into valid Date instances, then subtract their Unix times.

Comment: @Asad the duplicated question has no explanation on what goes on. Copy pasting is not learning.

Comment: @jQuerybeast The code is self explanatory. I've edited the answer to elaborate anyway.

Comment: Here's one implementation: http://jsbin.com/eginup/1/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
function comp(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.result.date).getTime() - new Date(b.result.date).getTime();
}

your_array.sort(comp);
```

Just to extend @Karthikr's comment.

```js
var result = [];

result.push({
  id: 'ID',
  result: {
    url: 'test',
    date: '15 May 2013, 6:40 pm'
  }
}, {
  id: 'ID',
  result: {
    url: 'test',
    date: '20 Dec 2012, 8:00 am'
  }
}, {
  id: 'ID',
  result: {
    url: 'test',
    date: '29 Jun 2012, 5:47 pm'
  }
});

function comp(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.result.date).getTime() - new Date(b.result.date).getTime();
}

result.sort(comp);

$('body').append(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 5* what an amazing solution! legend.

Comment: Hi, i need more help in this i want to sort data by descending order? how to sort it?

Comment: Just switch the `a` and `b` in the `return` line.