# Javascript - Sort nested array containing objects ascending and descending according to date

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

Below is my json data:

```
var homes={
"ERROR": "SUCCESS",
"DATA": [
    {
        "BookingID": "9513",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "91157307",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 13:00:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "95117317",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 13:30:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "957266",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-12 19:15:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "74",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 12:21:00"
    }
]
};
```

I want to sort the array according to `DutyStart`(in date format) in Descending and Ascending order using **Javascript** only and append the data to body or alert the sorted array.

I tried the solution from[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574309/sort-json-array-by-date-key) but iam not able to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hint. You can even compare those date strings without converting them into a Date. Have you tried something?

Comment: @OgnjenBabic i tried solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574309/sort-json-array-by-date-key but the issue is that the are creating a json like `[{...}]` but i have `{a:xxx, b:[{..}]}`. as iam new to this iam not able to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple bubble sort for your data, sorting by the date:

```js
var homes={
"ERROR": "SUCCESS",
"DATA": [
    {
        "BookingID": "9513",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "91157307",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 13:00:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "95117317",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 13:30:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "957266",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-12 19:15:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "74",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 12:21:00"
    }
]
};


var list = homes.DATA.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.DutyStart - b.DutyStart;
});
console.log(list);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why not something like `homes.DATA.sort(sortFn(a, b))`?

Comment: Thanks @RobG. Updated answer to reflect

Answer (score 1):

You can [*sort*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) very easily on ISO 8601-like date strings since they work as strings as well as numbers would.

Pass the values to a sort function and return 0, 1 or -1 depending the comparison, e.g.

```js
// Data
var homes={
"ERROR": "SUCCESS",
"DATA": [
    {
        "BookingID": "9513",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 12:00:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "91157307",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 13:00:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "95117317",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 13:30:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "957266",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-12 19:15:00"
    },
    {
        "BookingID": "74",
        "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 12:21:00"
    }
]
};

// Sort - operates on the original array
homes.DATA.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.DutyStart < b.DutyStart? -1 : (a.DutyStart == b.DutyStart? 0 : 1); 
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(homes.DATA));
```

Comment: Thanks @RobG. can u please explain what this means  **Pass the values to a sort function and return 0, 1 or -1 depending the comparison** and how to sort in **ascending and descending**.

Comment: It's a explanation of the code. You can reverse the order of the sort by reversing the comparison outcome, so instead of `a < b? -1 : (a == b? 0 : 1)` swap -1 and 1: `a < b? 1 : (a == b? 0 : -1)`. There are many questions here about sorting arrays, search for some.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for this task, because it compares strings and while the data are [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date strings, they can be sorted directly with this method.

```js
var homes = { "ERROR": "SUCCESS", "DATA": [{ "BookingID": "9513", "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 12:00:00" }, { "BookingID": "91157307", "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 13:00:00" }, { "BookingID": "95117317", "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 13:30:00" }, { "BookingID": "957266", "DutyStart": "2016-02-12 19:15:00" }, { "BookingID": "74", "DutyStart": "2016-02-11 12:21:00" }] };

homes.DATA.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.DutyStart.localeCompare(b.DutyStart);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(homes, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```